# Explanation of the Marching Squares saddle points resolution

Tags: algorithm, 2d-graphics

I was reading the Wikipedia entry on Marching Squares, and was confused by the explanation of the saddle point disambiguation:

Ambiguous Case:

[image]

Basically, given the saddle points, the ambiguity is resolved by using the average data value for the center of the cell. I don't understand why this would help resolve the ambiguity. It seems to just select the longer pair of lines over the shorter pair. Is there any reason for this approach?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares#Disambiguation_of_saddle_points

Comment: "It seems to just select the longer pair of lines over the shorter pair." What? All the red lines in the figure are the same length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine that a black dot represents a value of -1 whereas a white dot represents a value of +1. You are looking for the iso-line(s) where each point upon the line is 0.

For this example you could either place the iso-lines like on the left or the right:

[image] or [image]

The difference between the solutions is the value in the center. In the left case we assume 1s whereas in the right solution we assume -1s. So we check the center value and based on that value decide which solution fits best. If the center value is 1, we pick the left solution. If the center value is -1, we choose the right solution.

Comment: But what if the values are all different ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which values do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

That disambiguation method *often* selects the **shorter** pair of line segments over the longer pair.

A different method which can be shown (with some algebra) to *always* select the shorter pair of line segments over the longer pair is based on bilinear interpolation, i.e. fitting a polynomial of the form
***axy* + *bx* + *cy* + *d***
to the given data values at the 4 corners of the cell.

The contour curve at height ***h*** is the locus of points **(*x*, *y*)** that satisfy
***axy* + *bx* + *cy* + *d* - *h* = 0**.

Such a contour curve is a hyperbola, which has 2 branches.  The portion of each branch of the hyperbola inside the cell is then approximated with a line segment connecting the intersection points of that branch with the 2 cell edges that it intersects.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on the answer by user3405743, using a bilinear model, we have that the intersection curve is an hyperbola with axis-aligned asymptotes, so we link the left intersection to the top or bottom one, whichever is leftmost (the segment lengths themselves are unimportant).

[image]

The piecewise bilinear model is appropriate in that it defines a continuous surface.